# To make a pane scrollable in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Can you please tell me, how can I make a pane scrollable? I am able to make an image scrollable, like this:

```
        VBox root = new VBox();
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.png"))));
        root.getChildren().add(sp);
```

But when I am trying to make a whole pane scrollable, which consists of some Buttons and a small animation, there happens nothing regarding scrollbars. There are no scrollbars. How can I solve that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do it by myself, and it is because your scroll pane has fixed width and height, by resizing window, your `scroll pane` doesn't resize on itself. You can use `anchor pane` so scroll pane will resize with `anchor pane`. You could do something like this:

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("wp1951596.jpg"));
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(image);
    scrollPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 0.);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 0.);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 0.);
    rootPane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
```

I would also recommend you using JavaFX with .fxml files. Then you can create your layout in SceneBuilder and it will make everything easier and faster.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your advice regarding sceneBuilder. Now I know what the rules for nesting containers are. Now I have always scrollbars of my scrollPane, with AnchorPane. Unfortunately now I’m facing with another Problem, because when I scale my image, the scrollpane doesn’t work anymore. I think I have to solve it programmatically, because there is a need for registration of listeners. Probably the scrollPane must be updated every time when the image changes his size. Nevertheless I will mark your answer as best answer, because of the learning effect from the screenBuilder.